# MySql selecting greatest difference between 2 rows within the past day

Tags: mysql

I have a table that sort of looks like this

```
id  |  name  |  c1  |  c2  |  c3  |  c4  |  time
-------------------------------------------------
 1  |  miley |  23  |  11  |  21  |  18  |  2013-01-13 20:26:25
 2  |  john  |  31  |  29  |  23  |  27  |  2013-01-14 20:26:25
 3  |  steve |  44  |  31  |  33  |  35  |  2013-01-14 20:26:25
 4  |  miley |  34  |  44  |  47  |  48  |  2013-01-15 08:26:25
 5  |  john  |  27  |  53  |  49  |  52  |  2013-01-15 08:26:25
 6  |  steve |  27  |  62  |  50  |  64  |  2013-01-16 08:26:25
 7  |  miley |  44  |  54  |  57  |  87  |  2013-01-16 20:26:25
 8  |  john  |  37  |  93  |  59  |  62  |  2013-01-17 20:26:25
 9  |  steve |  85  |  71  |  87  |  74  |  2013-01-17 20:26:25
...etc
```

*note: this is a random table I made up to just give you an idea of what my table looks like

I need to grab the name for who had the greatest change in a specific column over the course of a specific date range. I've tried a bunch of different queries by can't get one to work. I think my closest solution is something like...

```
SELECT table1.name, MAX(table1.c1-h.c1) as maxDiff 
FROM table_a as table1
LEFT JOIN table_a as table2 
ON table2.name=table1.name AND table1.c1>table2.c1
WHERE table2.c1 IS NOT NULL
```

What am I doing wrong? To be clear, I want to be able to select a range of dates then determine who has the biggest difference for that date range in a determined column. Also note that the data only increments over time, so the first capture of any day will always be <= the last capture of the day for that person.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: I need the name and their total difference of whoever had the greatest difference during a specific daterange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you will be needing a nested query.  First, a query of each person on their own measurements within the date range, then order it by the biggest and take the top 1... something like this may work for you...

```
select
      PreGroupByName.`Name`,
      PreGroupByName.MaxC1 - PreGroupByName.MinC1 as MaxSpread
   from
      ( select 
              t1.`Name`,
              min( t1.c1 ) as MinC1,
              max( t1.c1 ) as MaxC1
           from
              table_a t1
           where
              t1.`time` between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-17'  -- or whatever date/time range
           group by
              t1.`Name` ) as PreGroupByName
   order by
      MaxSpread DESC
   limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    `id`,`name`
    ,MAX(`c1`)-MIN(`c1`) AS `diff_c1`
    -- ,MAX(`c2`)-MIN(`c2`) AS `diff_c2`
    -- ,MAX(`c3`)-MIN(`c3`) AS `diff_c3`
    -- ,MAX(`c4`)-MIN(`c4`) AS `diff_c4`
FROM `the_table`
WHERE `time` BETWEEN '2013-01-13 20:26:25' AND '2013-01-17 20:26:25'
GROUP BY `name`
ORDER BY `diff_c1` DESC -- whichever you want to evaluate
LIMIT 1
```